# How do I use Word.Interop to open a template stored in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-word, automation

I have an application that is used for engineers to track air quality evaluations for industry clients.
If the clients are in compliance with state regulations, a letter is written by our engineers informing them of this, with a lot of relevant data contained within the letter, manually captured from the application. 
What I want to do is store a template of the letter in the database and let the engineers press a button to auto generate the letter with the database stored data filled into the provided tags in the template.

Every bit of this is relatively easy to accomplish.  The one piece that I am having an issue with is using Word Interop to open the template stored in the database.

The command:

```
oWord.Documents.Add(ref wordfile, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Requires a `filepath/name` for the first argument.

How can I direct it to open a new document from a template stored in a database table?

I specifically want the template stored in the database to make alterations much easier to accomplish, as this will definitely change over time.  I appreciate any assistance that can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would have the application grab the template from the DB and stream it to a temp file. Then your application can just open the temp file.

You can use the [Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) function to get a temporary file to write to. Then after you create the file and save it/send it, just clean up the temp file.

I have created a wrapper class called [TemporaryFile](http://code.google.com/p/stuce-dot-net-utilities/) that can be used with a using statement to generate the temp file and clean it up when you are done. It's not perfect and probably doesn't need the mutex it creates, but you are welcome to use it/modify it as you see fit (MIT license)